# Checking if Shared Preferences Exist

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Trying to check if if Shared Preferences exist or not. What I need is to allow the user to arrive on a page if they have been here before (i.e. shared preferences exist and are not equal to "") or put them to the welcome page if it is their first time on the app (i.e. shared preferences are blank as user hasn't entered any data).

```
public class PersonalDetails extends Activity {
        private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;  


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_details);


if (sharedPreferences.contains("")) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(PersonalDetails.this, Welcome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: You have to form the actual question or add a stacktrace if you're experiencing any errors. BTW, calling `contains()` method on an uninitialised SharedPreferences object should raise NullPointerException

Comment: Any idea how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think getPreferences needs two inputs as below.

```
public abstract SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name,
        int mode);
// Example 
getSharedPreferences("your_app_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Just input a string ("your_app_name") into your old getSharedPreferences function as shown it is shown in my comment above.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry didnt see it in your code. Does this go into the onCreate or the method?